# Submit NLP classification model to Kaggle

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, kaggle

I am having a hard time converting my RNN/NLP model to Kaggle competition in csv file. I am a total beginner in file converting. I am already at the point where I am comparing my test model to validation data set, but I am not sure how to convert those to predict in pandas, tabular, csv format. Here is the link to the competition: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/learn-ai-bbc/data

Loading the file part:

```
with open("./bbc-text.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    print(f"First line (header) looks like this:\n\n{csvfile.readline()}")
    print(f"Each data point looks like this:\n\n{csvfile.readline()}")
```

This is my model:

```
def create_model(num_words, embedding_dim, maxlen):
    
    tf.random.set_seed(123)
    
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([ 
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ])
    
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy']) 

    return model
```

testing and validating part:

```
model = create_model(NUM_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, MAXLEN)

history = model.fit(train_padded_seq, train_label_seq, epochs=30, validation_data=(val_padded_seq, val_label_seq))
```

I tried adding the test.csv file to `model.predict`, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you provide more information about? Probably the code that you wrote

Comment: @HarshadPatil Sure, it's pretty long and in notebook format, so could you tell me are there any specific part of the code you need?

Comment: I added more codes